# Connecting Kindle's E Ink display to Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: display, eink

I have a broken Amazon Kindle with working E Ink display.

Is it possible to connect it to Raspberry Pi B+?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you followed up on the kindle display stuff done previously?
https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/kindleberry-pi-the-second/